# Is it harmful to battery if we use it during charing, from solor panels or electricity?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated

For lead acid, dry and tall tubler Batteries.

Comment: You can't charge and draw a battery at the same time. If you try to draw power from a battery while it is charging you instead just draw power directly from the charger.

Comment: A UPS does exactly that the incoming power covers the load and charges the battery or keeps it charged - when the incoming power fails the battery delivers with no switching time, unlike a standby power supply.

Answer (score 1):

A battery is a lumped element, so it's either charging or discharging, not both.  If your load is active, it might charge more slowly depending on the load and charger characteristics.  However, that in itself won't harm the battery.

Comment: Thanks! u help a lot.

Comment: Also same for mobile batteries ?

Comment: @Coder1 What is a mobile battery? What Cristobol said should apply to any battery, though.

Comment: Common batteries that used in mobiles phones.

Comment: Does it is same for batteries used in mobile phones?

Comment: In my experience, "fast charging" tends to wear out a battery prematurely - I suggest avoiding fast chargers. "Slow charging" them, through a regular charger, or by using the phone while it is charging (thus reducing the charging rate) *seems* to slightly increase the lifespan of the battery. Temperature (too hot, too cold) also seems to reduce battery lifespan. This is for current Lithium technologies - we may soon see a new "solid glass" battery with much better performance.

Comment: Yes, the same for mobile phone batteries, except that there the phone is probably managing the charging internally.

Answer (score 1):

There are charge cycles at different stages of battery state and temperature.

If you choose the float voltage, this would be ok to charge and use.